# Football pool question

Tags: probability

I'm in a football pool where before the game is played, we pick numbers from 0 to 9 from a bag. The winner is whoever picks the number that is the sum of the last number of the two scores. Eg. 32-27, the winning number would be 9. My question is, are my odds of winning better the earlier that I pick?

Comment: Makes no difference.  Your chances of getting any number are 10% for each number regardless of when you choose.  Instead of picking from a bag imagine placing the number hidden, face down, in front of each person.  Order had no bearing on the odds of getting any one number.  As far as what Simon S says, yes, some final digits are certainly more popular.  If you are talking North American football, a two is rarer.  But if you're asking if choosing your number early helps, then no.

Comment: @SimonS OP didn't say that he'd get to choose the number he picks.  He said he'd be drawing from a bag.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how order makes no difference, let's look at the chance of drawing a $7$, say, going first or going tenth.  Going first, your chance is $10\%$, clearly.  But going last, your chance of getting the $7$ is the chance of everybody in front of you drawing something that is NOT a $7$.  Which is $$\frac{9}{10}\times\frac{8}{9}\times\frac{7}{8}\times\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{5}\times\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{10}$$